# Is there a way to show all warehouses in a Streamlit application running on Snowflake?

Tags: python, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Streamlit native app running on Snowflake and I would like to show a dropdown menu of all warehouses in the user's account.

In my **setup.sql** script, I created a stored procedure **get_available_warehouses()** with the following Python code:

```
def get_available_warehouses(cls, session: Session):
        session.sql("SHOW WAREHOUSES").collect()
        return session.sql("SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))").collect()
```

My Streamlit app then calls this stored procedure like this:

```
session.sql("call public.get_available_warehouses()")
```

When I do that, the stored procedure fails with the following message:

```
query_id_place_holder_XYZ not found
```

It seems to be a problem with running **LAST_QUERY_ID()**. A solution to this problem seems to add **EXECUTE AS CALLER** when defining the stored procedure.

But now, when I do that, the app won't even install because I get the following message:

```
Procedure 'GET_AVAILABLE_WAREHOUSES' cannot be created/altered. Application can only own owner's rights stored procedures.
```

Do you have any idea? Ultimately, maybe I don't even need to do this, I just want to get a list of the user's warehouses.

Comment: Are you using the right role that can actually run those SQL statements?

Comment: @Sergiu I think so, but normally running LAST_QUERY_ID() should not require any specific role, no?